# get a value from ini file and decrypt it in powerbuilder script

Tags: encryption, ini, powerbuilder

Iam working in powerbuilder and i made two functions the first function called `of_enc()` for encrypt a string and the second function called `of_dec()` for decrypt, i encrypet a value in `inifile` by using the encryption function, the value is encrypted succssfully by using `SetProfileString (ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass", of_enc("password"))` 
now after that i need to decrypt the value in another window by using`of_dec()` but i can't access the ecrypted value in the `inifile` . any idea on how to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

```
password = ProfileString(ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass", "")
password = of_enc(password)
```

*** Note that this function can only return a string which has a maximum length of 4096 characters.

Comment: I don't want to encrypt the value! I want to decrypt it but i can't access the value in the `inifile` , the encryption is done succssfully by using the statement `SetProfileString (ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass", of_enc("password"))` but how to access the stored  value in the `inifile` @shenn

Answer (score 0):

i think i found what i am looking for . this statement is accessing the stored value in the `inifile` and working fine with the decryption function:

```
of_dec(ProfileString(ls_inifile, "Database", "DBPass",""))
```